# Centering a button and responsive design

Tags: button, responsive-design, center

I have a simple question about responsive design. I have a button that I want on the top right of the screen on PC but on the bottom center on mobile. Do I need to use @media or is there another way? I've tried `text-align` but it doesnt seem to work

```css
.boton {
    position: relative;
    left: 80%;
    top:5%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .boton {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<a href="mymail0@gmail.com">
        <button class="boton">Contact Me</button>
    </a>
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap

Comment: no,i'm just learning the basic with visual studio code

Comment: there is well responsive css classes defined in bootstrap you should use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Transform` property to do that, Just make element go `50%` in `left` and `translate` it to `-50%` in x-axis means horizontally. Hope it works check out snippet. And you don't need to specify the pos`i`tion property when you are going to mobile screen, unless you don't want to change it as per your `screen-width`.

```css
.boton {
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
  top:5%;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
.boton {
  text-align:center;
  left : 50%;
  transform : translateX(-50%);
 }
}
```

```html
<a href="mymail0@gmail.com">
        <button class="boton">Contact Me</button>
    </a>
```